# Repairing/Replacing Concrete Sidewalk Expansion Material

Tags: repair, joints, sidewalk

I have several expansion joints in my home’s concrete sidewalks that need to be repaired/refilled.  There is a lot of info regarding this out on Internet…too much in fact.  I can’t determine from online research if it is most appropriate to use asphalt impregnated felt/fiber board for this, or if foam backer rod and Sika-flex is what is required (or best solution).  Areas to be repaired are about 1/2-3/4 inches wide, ~4 feet long, and ~4 inches deep (i.e. fairly typical).

I prefer the look of the fiber board; if I decide to go with it, I am not sure how best to fix or “glue” it in place?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't really matter what the material is as long as it prevents rigid materials, such as sand and ice, from occupying the space. Don't overthink it.

If you go with fiberboard, I wouldn't worry about bonding it in place. The asphalt will do that to some extent, but friction will do most of the work. The drawback to fiberboard is in sizing--it may not fit exactly as it did when the concrete was poured.